# ImportError: No module named bs4 in django

Tags: python, django, pycharm, beautifulsoup

I am learning Django and I was working with bs4 in PyCharm on mac. I am using Python3 with Django which also has bs4 installed and it can be seen below.
[image]

But when I run the project, it throws me an error saying bs4 does not exist which can be seen below.
[image]

I have tried a lot of ways and it couldn't get it to work. Help

Comment: You installed bs4 in Python 3.5. As you can see - if you bother to read the error message - you're running your project with Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are running the script with Python2.7 (according to the traceback) while having `beautifulsoup4` package installed in Python3.5 environment.

*Adjust your run configuration to use Python3.5 to run the script.*

Answer (score 1):

ok first thing, in your python 3 environment you have installed bs4, but in your python 2.7, you probably do not have. As you can see in your attached second screen, django is running on python 2.7.

I recommend using virtual environment, where you can have all of your dependencies personalized for single project. In fact, every project you are working on, should have its own separate virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks. I used python manage.py runserver instead of python manage.py runserver

Answer (score 0):

You've installed wrong Beautiful Soup package. The one that you installed is [bs4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bs4/0.0.1)

> This is a dummy package managed by the developer of Beautiful Soup to prevent name squatting. The official name of PyPI’s Beautiful Soup Python package is beautifulsoup4.

The one that you need to install is [beautifulsoup4](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4). Which you should get with `pip install beautifulsoup4` and not `pip install bs4`